# windows phone localization for English countries

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a question about Windows Phone localization. I checked culture and language support for windows phone, for English, there's only English (United States) and English (United Kingdom). I also want to ad English support for Canada and Australia, so how can I do that? Also The display language setting in emulator only has English (United States) and English (United Kingdom) for English, so how can I test other English countries such as Canada and Australia? Thanks!

Fei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 has a limited support matrix right now for culture/language combinations. You can see [this language support list on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202918%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).  I would recommend coding to en-CA for Canada if you desire it.

There's some guidance on how to support non-supported languages in WP7 from Microsoft if you view ["How do I localize for a language that isn't supported?" section](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/04/02/globalizing-and-localizing-a-windows-phone-app.aspx).  You're not going to like it though.  Here's the snippet of the steps.

> 1. Hard code your app to be written in the unsupported language, if you don't plan on supporting more languages in the future. OR, create
>      your default AppResources.resx file and put your unsupported language
>      strings in there, if you plan on supporting more languages in the
>      future or will support additional languages in your submission.
> 2. Set your neutral language to one of the supported display languages. For example, 'English (United States)'.
> 3. On App Hub, you will be prompted to input metadata and a description for the neutral language you chose (for the above example,
>      you'll be prompted for English). You must include the following three
>      items in the 'Detailed description' field to pass certification:
>
> A note, such as ‘The language of this application is [unsupported
>   language name]’. This note must be written in the same language as the
>   neutral language. For example, if you chose 'English (United States)'
>   as your neutral language, the note must be written in English (United
>   States). This note must be the first item in the ‘Detailed
>   description’ field. Your app description, in the same language as the
>   neutral language. Your app description, in the unsupported language.

I would also recommend sticking it in an en-CA file so you can easily swap to it if/when support comes.